# How to join two tables in HQL to fetch results for one domain class

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes

```
class User {
    transient springSecurityService
    String username
    String password
}

Class Request {
    String type
}
```

I join the two with a separate class as recommended by Burt

```
class UserRequest implements Serializable{
    User user
    Request request

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['user', 'request']
        version false
    }

    //equals & hashcode

    static UserRequest create (User user, Request request, boolean flush = true) {
        def d = new UserRequest (user: user, request: request)
                d.save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }
}
```

**Question**

How can I write a method that would fetch all requests for a user and takes into account `max` and `offset` for pagination and then returns `List<Request>`

**What I've tried**

```
static List<Request> getAllRequestForUser(User user, params) {
    Request.findAll "from Request a , UserRequest b 
     where b.user = :userId and 
           a.id = b.request.id and  
           a.type = :foo",
    [foo: "BAR",userId: user.id],
    [max: params.max?: 10, offset: params.offset?: 0]
}
```

As you can see I wish to return `List<Request>` so that in my list page I can do something like this:

```
<g:each in="${requestList}" status="i" var="requestInstance">
            <tr>
                <td>${requestInstance.type}</td>
            </tr>
</g:each>
```

**Problem**

However, I can't access the property `type` because the returned objects in the list are of type `Object` rather then `Request`

How can I fix this?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that the collection contains instances of `Object` and not some subclass there of. What makes you think that is the case?

Comment: It makes me think that is the case because the `g:each` I have to iterate over the list won't let me access the properties of the `Request` class. Additionally, `println UserRequest.getAllRequestForUser(user,params)[0].class.getName()` prints out `Object`

Comment: Ok, `Request.findAll 'from ...' ` does not wither, rather  `Request.executeQuery(Select a from Request a, UserRequest b...` works. I find it odd that there are several ways of doing the same thing and some of which don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to tell Hibernate how to join, that was already configured at startup:

```
static List<Request> getAllRequestForUser(User user, params) {
   UserRequest.executeQuery(
      'select ur.request from UserRequest ur ' +
      'where ur.user=:user and ur.request.type=:type',
      [type: 'BAR', user: user],
      [max: params.max?: 10, params.offset?: 0])
```

Comment: I understand, Thanks! One more thing.. Why does `UserRequest.executeQuery` work but not `UserRequest.findAll` ?

Comment: I forget the differences and looking just now in `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi` the code is identical, but since `executeQuery` always works and is really a thin wrapper around native Hibernate HQL execution, I just use that.